# Error 2 Invalid expression term ')'

Tags: c#, windows

I'm new to c# more experienced with c++ so heres my code
Did i forget to add something i don't think i did if i did id thank for a response! :)

Note:I have read the similar questions but did not understand the answers well  the program is personal venture into a new language.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Input_Program
{
    class Program
    {
       private static void Main()
        {

           Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my bool program!");
           Console.WriteLine("Input a NON capital y or n when told to.");


            char Y = 'y';
            char N = 'n';

            if()
            {}
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Please do not remove the entire question when it has been answered. It makes the entire question worthless for ones who stumbled upon the same problem by Google/Search. I've rolled back it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have an empty `if()`. The compiler tells you it expects an expression before the closing paren.

Comment: Thanks all of you who have answered my question!

Answer (score 3):

The error is pointing to the empty parens in the "if () {}" --there must be a boolean expression inside the parentheses.